# WPF DataGrid - key that put a cell in editmode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using DataGrid key press events in my key down preview and key up events. Is there a way to detect whether a key will put the grid into edit mode (and detect this before the BeginningEdit callback) so I can anticipate edit mode on editable cells rather that handling those key presses is a special way?

What's the best way to test if a key will put a cell into edit mode?

```
void DataGrid_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (CanEnterCellEditMode(e.Key))
        return;
    else if (e.Key == Key.Escape) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this? Just wondering if there might be an easier way

Comment: Certain key presses have other functions depending on the context. If any keypress will put a focused cell into edit mode I want to know about it in the key down preview and return before any other handling of that keypress.

Comment: I guess any e.Key that is printable (or Key.Back / Key.Delete) are going to put the cell into edit mode, so you could write your CanEnterCellEditMode method to check for certain ranges of the e.Key enum?

Comment: Yup look like this is the only way to go.